# Best Linear Approximant

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

I want to solve the following approximation error problem $$\min_{x\in S}\|Ax-b\|_p$$. Here $A$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, $b$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x$ is in $\mathbb{R}^d$. $n \gt d$ and $p$ is a norm between $1 \leq p \leq \infty$

$S$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. This would ensure that the minimization always exists.

Suppose I know $b$ is bounded in the $p$ norm.

Can I say that the value of $$\min_{x\in S}\|Ax-b\|_p$$ would also be finite?

Comment: Why should it not be finite? your objective function is continuous on a compact set.

Comment: I agree, however notice that if $b$ was not bounded in the $p$ norm it could have blown up

Comment: Typically $b$ is fixed. Even  if you are interested in $\min_{x\in S, b\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|Ax-b\|_p$  your minimum will be finite.

Comment: Is this true even if say $b$ is bounded in some other norm $q$ rather than the norm on which I am taking a projection which is $p$?

Comment: For example I say $b$ is finite in $\| \|_{\infty}$ Will $\|Ax - b\|_2$ be finite?. Maybe this is apparant to you. I cant see it however

Comment: Why should not it be true: $$\min_{x\in S, b\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|Ax-b\|_p\leq \|Ax_0-b_0\|_p$$ doe any $x_0\in S$ and $b_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: all the $\ell_p$ norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent: there are constants $c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1\|x\|_p\leq \|x\|_1\leq c_2\|x\|_p$. Furthermore, all topologies on a finite dimensional space are equivalent, so  $\{b\}$ is always compact.

Comment: Thanks. This clears up